# Waiving moral rights to Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988

Tags: copyright, contract-law

I have a contract of employment for a new job, with the following clause.

*15.6.  You agree to permanently waive all moral rights (if any) conferred by Chapter IV of Part I of the Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988 for any work to which this clause applies.*

The part mentioned: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/part/I/chapter/IV

The part referred to (as I understand it) is to do with the right of a creator to be recognised as such, but I'm not sure I fully understand it. Is the clause there so the company can claim to be the creator of any works I create while there?

**Edit**

Note, this contract is for an engineering job. The specific clause in the contract looks to relate more to artistic works which is why I am unsure of its true meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, since you are an employee the company **is** the owner of any copyright material you create under the work for hire principle.

Moral rights belong to the individual and include (among other things) a right to be attributed as the author. They can be transferred by contract as your employer is requiring. For engineering/architectural firms this is standard practice to do this as it is unworkable to identify every engineer and draftsperson who worked on every drawing/specification.

Comment: Ahh I see. I thought it would be a standard thing, but I'd never seen the term 'wave moral rights' before.